# awk search then transpose rows to columns

Tags: search, awk

quite new to awk and data manipulation but have got stuck and was looking for some help.

have a file: Ntab.txt which is a sample file of two hosts, there is numerous hosts in the real file one after each other.

Each host has multiple "displayName"s (addresses) with corresponding figures for each 'displayName'.

```html
>cat Ntab.txt
name    devtwr1
displayName     00:67:BB
capacityInKB    104,857,600
consumedCapacityInKB    4,042,752
dpPoolID        20
displayName     00:7B:FD
capacityInKB    52,428,800
consumedCapacityInKB    14,880,768
dpPoolID        10
displayName     00:7C:28
capacityInKB    34,179,712
consumedCapacityInKB    29,804,544
dpPoolID        20
displayName     00:7C:29
capacityInKB    34,179,712
consumedCapacityInKB    5,462,016
dpPoolID        20
name    devtwr2
displayName     00:67:BB
capacityInKB    104,857,600
consumedCapacityInKB    4,042,752
dpPoolID        20
displayName     00:7B:FD
capacityInKB    52,428,800
consumedCapacityInKB    14,880,768
dpPoolID        10
displayName     00:7C:28
capacityInKB    34,179,712
consumedCapacityInKB    29,804,544
dpPoolID        20
displayName     00:7C:29
capacityInKB    34,179,712
consumedCapacityInKB    5,462,016
dpPoolID        20
```

I need to be able to produce the $2 data from the rows into columns after each 'name' (host) and in csv type format, headings optional. I cant use (,:) as separators as the data includes them so either (tab or ;).

Like:

```html
name;displayName;capacityInKB;consumedCapacityInKB;dpPoolID        
devtwr1;00:67:BB;104,857,600;4,042,752;20
 ;00:7B:FD;52,428,800;14,880,768;10
 ;00:7C:28;34,179,712;29,804,544;20
 ;00:7C:29;34,179,712;5,462,016;20
devtwr2;00:67:BB;104,857,600;4,042,752;20
 ;00:7B:FD;52,428,800;14,880,768;10
 ;00:7C:28;34,179,712;29,804,544;20
 ;00:7C:29;34,179,712;5,462,016;20
```

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked for `awk`, and should accept John1024's solution if it works for you.  But this is the sort of problem where I would reach for Perl instead.  This is one solution in that language.  It has a slight advantage (IMO) in that it is not dependent upon the specific order of the fields in each record, apart from `displayName` signalling the start of a new set.

```
$ perl -lane '
BEGIN {
  @fields = qw(name displayName capacityInKB consumedCapacityInKB dpPoolID);
  print join ";", @fields;
}
if (/^(name|displayName)/ && $data{displayName}) {
  print join ";", @data{@fields};
  %data = ( name => $data{name} );
}
$data{$F[0]} = $F[1];
END {
  print join ";",@data{@fields};
}' ntab.txt
```

Output:

```
name;displayName;capacityInKB;consumedCapacityInKB;dpPoolID
devtwr1;00:67:BB;104,857,600;4,042,752;20
devtwr1;00:7B:FD;52,428,800;14,880,768;10
devtwr1;00:7C:28;34,179,712;29,804,544;20
devtwr1;00:7C:29;34,179,712;5,462,016;20
devtwr2;00:67:BB;104,857,600;4,042,752;20
devtwr2;00:7B:FD;52,428,800;14,880,768;10
devtwr2;00:7C:28;34,179,712;29,804,544;20
devtwr2;00:7C:29;34,179,712;5,462,016;20
```

Comment: Thanks Guys, Both options work Fantastic... one last additional thing i didn't for see.. when using the data having a null in the additional lines causes issues... Is there a way to repeat the host name e.g. "devtwr1" for each null in the following rows? i.e.devtwr1;00:67:BB;104,857,600;4,042,752;20
 devtwr1;00:7B:FD;52,428,800;14,880,768;10
 devtwr1;00:7C:28;34,179,712;29,804,544;20
 devtwr1;00:7C:29;34,179,712;5,462,016;20

Comment: Sure, Graham - we explicitly had to do extra work to exclude it from the other lines to match your desired output. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this does what you want:

```
$ awk '$1=="name"{name=$2} $1 ~/^(displayName|capacityInKB|consumedCapacityInKB)$/{out=out";"$2} $1=="dpPoolID"{print name out";"$2; name=" "; out=""}' Ntab.txt
devtwr1;00:67:BB;104,857,600;4,042,752;20
 ;00:7B:FD;52,428,800;14,880,768;10
 ;00:7C:28;34,179,712;29,804,544;20
 ;00:7C:29;34,179,712;5,462,016;20
devtwr2;00:67:BB;104,857,600;4,042,752;20
 ;00:7B:FD;52,428,800;14,880,768;10
 ;00:7C:28;34,179,712;29,804,544;20
 ;00:7C:29;34,179,712;5,462,016;20
```

#### How it works

`awk` reads through each line one at a time.  Each line is divided into fields.  The first field is called `$1` and the second `$2`.

- `$1=="name"{name=$2}`

  This captures the name in the variable `name`.
- `$1~/^(displayName|capacityInKB|consumedCapacityInKB)$/{out=out";"$2}`

  When we come across any line for `displayName`, `capacityInKB`, or`consumedCapacityInKB`, append its value to the variable `out`.
- `$1=="dpPoolID"{print name out";"$2; name=" "; out=""}`

  When we reach the line for `dpPoolID`, print out the collected values.  Reset `out` to empty and set `name` to a space.

#### Keeping the name for each row

As an alternative output format, we can keep the name and show it on each row:

```
$ awk '$1=="name"{name=$2} $1 ~/^(displayName|capacityInKB|consumedCapacityInKB)$/{out=out";"$2} $1=="dpPoolID"{print name out";"$2; out=""}' Ntab.txt
devtwr1;00:67:BB;104,857,600;4,042,752;20
devtwr1;00:7B:FD;52,428,800;14,880,768;10
devtwr1;00:7C:28;34,179,712;29,804,544;20
devtwr1;00:7C:29;34,179,712;5,462,016;20
devtwr2;00:67:BB;104,857,600;4,042,752;20
devtwr2;00:7B:FD;52,428,800;14,880,768;10
devtwr2;00:7C:28;34,179,712;29,804,544;20
devtwr2;00:7C:29;34,179,712;5,462,016;20
```

Comment: Shorter way `awk '{out=out?out";"$2:(/^name/?$2:" ;"$2)}$1=="dpPoolID"{print out;out=""}' file`

Comment: @Graham  _"Is there a way to repeat the host name e.g. "devtwr1" for each null in the following rows?"_  Yes, in fact, it takes less code.  See update.

Comment: Not sure if I'm supposed to ask another question relating to this thread again... BUT.

I've used the perl answer that mark has supplied, which works great, However if i need to add another field Like the "name" field which isn't repeated, in this instance osType. How do a add that field in the empty field of the data.. eg

    name;osType;displayName;capacityInKB;consumedCapacityInKB;dpPoolID
    SDC1NM519;;00:60:04;1,048,576;43,008;10